# Can admission/funding (PhD) of international student be cancelled due to corona virus situation?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding, covid-19

Is it possible that a school cancel the admission and/or funding of an international student because he/she cannot travel because of the current travel bans? What are the possible scenarios for the admitted graduate students of fall 20? Especially what might happen to the fund? Will it be canceled if one semester is deferred?

Comment: It is possible, yes. But the situation is chaotic and will remain so for at least a month longer. Probably more. But I think such decisions won't be taken lightly.

Comment: A major issue is that US embassies and consulates have stopped handling applications for visas and international may not be able to obtain visas or might not be able to travel to the US for other reasons.  If you're trying to start a graduate program in the fall of 2020 you should talk to the international students office at your institution to see what can be done.  Right now they probably won't have any firm answers for you.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: i don't understand your comment. Is it only about US graduate schools? Or do US embassies have anything to do with graduate schools in non-US countries?

Comment: Being able to legally enter the US is a reasonable precondition for being admitted to a gradschool in the US. So that is how the closure of US embassies influences US gradschool admissions from non-US countries.

Comment: @SolarMike: I am sorry but it is not clear to me. Is Brian Borchers talking about US schools? I cannot find any information that the question is about the US.

Comment: @MaartenBuis: I think I am missing something here. How do you all know this question is about US schools?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about US schools.  However, I wouldn't be surprised if other countries have similarly stopped processing visa applications.

Comment: @user111388 I don't say this is right (it actually annoys me greatly), but if people don't mention the country there is an almost 99.9999999% chance that the country involved is the US.

Comment: At my university (in Australia), we continue to enroll students remotely or a student can defer his/her study to the next session without losing his/her offer or scholarship.   With regards to visa, the Australian government has stopped granting visas for now due to the current situation.